# использование retutn true в map

Tags: javascript

обьясните плиз  зачем здесь return true

https://codepen.io/nikitos2004tester/pen/ExjOXJW

```
function t9() {
    let b9 = [3, "hello", 4, "world", 5, "hi"];
    let out = b9.filter(item => {
        if (typeof item == 'string') {
            b9_string.push(item);
            return true;
        };
        if (typeof item == 'number') {
            b9_num.push(item);
            return true;
        };
    });
    document.querySelector('.out-9').innerHTML +='числа:'+ b9_num;
    document.querySelector('.out-9-2').innerHTML += 'строки:'+b9_string;
}

document.querySelector('.b-9').onclick = t9;
```

Comment: В данном примере незачем, лучше спросить  у автора кода...

Comment: в заголовке вопроса речь идет про `map`, в примере кода используется `filter`

Answer (score 3):

Если колбек [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) возвращает true то в массив out попадет элемент, проходящий проверку, если нет, то нет